# How to reset a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a question with respect to `JScrollPane` and a `JTable`.

I have added a `JTable` to a `JScrollPane`, and added the `JScrollPane` to the `JPanel`. When I click on 'show' button, the `JTable` will be filled with contents from the database.

I also have another button `reset`, clicking on which will remove the contents of the `JTable`, and the `JScrollPane`. It is supposed to be doing that, but what happens is that, even after clicking the button, all the contents of the `JTable` and the `JScrollPane` still exists.

I used `revalidate()`, `reinstantiate()`, etc, but of no use. How do I make it work?

Comment: please post your code ,......

Comment: Here is my code :
http://pastebin.com/RjwbM94G

Comment: try my solution which is as given below

Comment: a) please show your code here b) please show an sscce instead of a snippet (which doesn't contain the part that should _remove the content_)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using a DefaultTableModel, then you just do:

```
model.setRowCount(0);
```

Comment: correct answer, given the less than complete question :-) Wildly guessing that the OP might want to reset the structure as well (the snippet reads in a completely new table)

Comment: I haven't used it but it seems like it will just remove all rows. But the question how to reset it means he wants to remove all data and reload the table.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove a row from a JTable, you need to remove the target row from the underlying [TableModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). If, for instance, your TableModel is an instance of [DefaultTableModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), you can remove a row by doing the following:

```
((DefaultTableModel)myJTable.getModel()).removeRow(rowToRemove);
```

**Updation 2**

To know the rows and delete from jtable

```
 int rows = myJTable.getRowCount();
 for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
 ((DefaultTableModel)myJTable.getModel()).removeRow(i);
```

Comment: Since I don't know how many rows are there, I think this won't work.

Comment: Not sure if this deserves a downvote or not. Yes, the removeRow() is used to delete rows. However, when deleting rows you need to start at the last row and decrement i by 1 until you reach zero, otherwise you will only delete half of the rows.

Comment: -1 for a) @camickr already noted the incorrect looping b) not using api designed to handle the remove _all_